# How do I keep a user logged into firebase after refresh in React.JS?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

When mounting a component, I'd like to render either a log in screen or the app, depending on wether the user in logged in. However, each time I refresh, the user is logged out. How would I keep them logged in?

### App Component:

```
 firebase.initializeApp(config); //init the firebase app...

class App extends Component {//this component renders when the page loads
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {user: firebase.auth().currentUser};//current user
}
render(){
    if (this.state.user) {//if you are logged in
          return (
            <Application/>
          );
    } else {//if you are not logged in
          return (
            <Authentication/>
          );
    }
}

}
```

This is the method I'm using to log in the user (which works fine):

```
let email = "some";
let password = "thing";
const auth = firebase.auth();
const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The user's token is automatically persisted to local storage, and is read when the page is loaded. This means that the user should automatically be authenticated again when you reload the page.

The most likely problem is that your code doesn't detect this authentication, since your `App` constructor runs before Firebase has reloaded and validated the user credentials. To fix this, you'll want to [listen for the (asynchronous) `onAuthStateChanged()` event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user), instead of getting the value synchronously.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    this.setState({ user: user });
  });
}
```

Comment: You also get some auth state persistence options that you might want to configure https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

Comment: How user token is persisted in local storage?. I want to do the similar thing to subscribed user.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue with Firebase in React. Even though Firebase has an internal persistence mechanisms, you may experience a flicker/glitch when reloading the browser page, because the `onAuthStateChanged` listener where you receive the authenticated user takes a couple of seconds. That's why I use the local storage to set/reset it in the onAuthStateChanged listener. Something like the following:

```
firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
  authUser
    ? localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser))
    : localStorage.removeItem('authUser')
});
```

Then it can be retrieved in the constructor of a React component when the application starts:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    authUser: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser')),
  };
}
```

You can read more about it over [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-firebase-auth-persistence/).

Comment: great answer this

Comment: Is it OK to store the user's information in localStorage?

Comment: @Robin, I've tried the suggestions here, still have a problem, posted a very similar question here (stackoverflow.com/q/64024613/2534233), what could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: What happens if the user leaves the website and the token expires? When they revisit, wouldn't there be a flash of authenticated data since localStorage still contains user information?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I feel this way is the best and the most simple.

```
  state = {authUser: null,show:'none'};
 
     componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
       if (user) { this.setState({ authUser: true,show:'block'})} 
       else { this.setState({ authUser: false,show:'none'})}
    })
  }
  return{ /*important*/ this.state.authuser==false?
     <Login/>
     :this.state.authuser==true?
        <Home style={{display:this.state.show}}/>
        :<div>/*show loading/spash page*/
        </div>
   }
```

You can also add routing to this with Home as the default route ('/' **do not use exact path use path instead**) and then make it auto reroute to the login or signup if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Often when someone reloads the page they get a glimpse of your page (before it reroutes to the 'login' at least it seemed to while I was developing...) and thus having the ability to have a splash page set up is quite nice for the user instead of seeing a flashing page... that being said there is _probably_ a better way of doing such things but for an MVP it's perfect hence the best and most simple way :) @Greg