# How to stop firebase re-auth() on every page reload in a react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, backend

So i have this great react app using firebase auth and firestore.
Everything working fine except

Whenever i reload the page while a user is already logged in... navbar links change for a second.
Looks like app automatically re-login(re-auth) the user on every page reload. Why so? How to get rid of it? Some look-alike code sample

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import firebase from 'firebase/App'

export const App = () => {
    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState()
    const auth = firebase.auth()

    useEffect(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user) {
                setIsAuth(true)
            } else {
                setIsAuth(false)
            }
        })
    }, [isAuth])

    return(
        <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route to="/signIn" component={Login} />
                <Route to="/signUp" component={SignUp} />
                <Route to="/signOut" component={SignOut} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I keep a user logged into firebase after refresh in React.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855851/how-do-i-keep-a-user-logged-into-firebase-after-refresh-in-react-js)

Comment: Nope.. that is completely different thing.

Comment: What you're seeing is the expected behavior: Firebase will refresh the user's ID token when you reload the page. Also see my explanation from earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149287/firebase-auth-currentuser-is-null-when-loading-the-page-user-loaded-when-authst/60153899#60153899, which includes a trick to detect that the user is (likely to be) authenticated slight earlier, without the flash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally fixed it.

Reason it was happening bcoz firebase servers were verifying the user on each page reload which took some time and cause flickering in navbar for half a second.

Solution has three easy steps

1. Once logged in, store the user as boolean on local storage.

   ```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
        if (user) {
            // store the user on local storage
            localStorage.setItem('user', true);
        } else {
            // removes the user from local storage on logOut
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
        }
    })
   ```
2. Check The user from local storage in navbar component

   ```
    const userLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    userLocal ? <SignedInLinks/> : <SignedOutLinks/>;
   ```
3. Remove user from local storage on logout

Comment: How did you handle the case where the auth token is expired? I am having a similar issue and thought of the same solution as you. Localstorage will still contain 'user' and you will show signedinlinks when the user is not actually authenticated.

Comment: @Marlon if the auth token expires wouldn't this hit the `onAuthStateChanged` with an undefined user?

Comment: Thats really bad practice, you shouldn't store anything that is connected with authentication in local storage, especially not this way where user can manually set 'user' to true and become authenticated.

Answer (score 2):

@illiterate.farmer You are almost right. Actually you should only save a flag, `isSignedIn=true or false` in the localStorage because saving the full `user` object makes your app vulnerable to hacking very easily.

Any javascript function can access the localStorage and thus it will expose you tokens that can be used to impersonate as a genuine user to your backend system.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too and I think Firebase's intended way of doing this is to use the FirebaseAuthConsumer... `providerId` is null when awaiting auth status.

Compare [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-silence-njcw2?file=/src/SignedInIndicator.tsx) where the "not signed in" content is rendered for a split second before the signed in content, with [this one](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-fast-go8kl?file=/src/SignedInIndicator.tsx) where no render happens until Firebase has told us whether or not the user is signed in. Will need to press the "Sign in" button on first load and then refresh to test behaviour.