# How to ensure user is logged in on refresh in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

so currently using this in my app

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            setUser(user)
            setLoaded(true)
        } else {
            setLoaded(true)
            console.log(user, 'USER NOT LOGGED IN')
        }
    })
}, [])
```

which is sort of fine and keeps the user logged in. but im getting issues where because it must kick in after the page load. a `login` button flashes in my nav. I replace it to show the users name after login. obviously this isn't ideal. if you refresh somewhere like facebook you'll only ever see the same thing on refresh. is there a recommended way in firebase to do this?

should I store something locally? there must be an elegant solution for this

Comment: it is better to avoid rendering any UI element until you find out that a user is logged in (you can display a loader or just do not render anything).

Comment: I guess that is one option but that will make my app "appear" to be performing slower

Comment: you can opt for locally saving user logged in or not instead of depend on Auth state changed, also,add check at button view to check if state changed or not, if changed then show button else return null. this will sort your flash issue. it's because render call as soon mounted so button flashes and after some time your Auth state called

Comment: I guess that is a bit out of your hands. Considering that each user connection varies.

Comment: @AngelSalazar true (and I know I'm not Amazon) but if you refresh amazon then it's super quick and never flashes. I think it must be possible somehow without having to effect performance

Comment: I guess it is "fast" because they server-side render their page and they use a different architecture.

Comment: @AngelSalazar I found this, it solved it for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855851/how-do-i-keep-a-user-logged-into-firebase-after-refresh-in-react-js

Comment: Robin's free courses are awesome. it makes sense storing the user in local storage and if this is staled data (user token has expired), it gets revalidated by the onAuthStateChanged

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did upvote? sorry it was the answer below yours. I've been using onauthstatechanged for a while and it is good but I needed something extra to ensure I didn't see a "flicker" in my app which Robin's answer provided. but don't worry I always upvote an answer in SO that helps me