# How do I keep the user logged into firebase after refresh in React.JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855851/how-do-i-keep-a-user-logged-into-firebase-after-refresh-in-react-js), the suggested answer doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is how I am using firebase mobile sign in for sign in ReactJS. I am also setting auth state persistence on sign in (see below code).

However when I refresh the page after sign in the user object disappears i.e "User is not signed in" message gets printed in componentDidMount.

What could I be doing wrong ?

```
class SignInScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isSignedIn: false, 
    };

  }

  // Configure FirebaseUI.
  uiConfig = {
    // Popup signin flow rather than redirect flow.
    signInFlow: "popup",

    signInOptions: [
      {
        provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        defaultCountry: "US",
      },
    ],
    callbacks: {
      // Avoid redirects after sign-in.
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: () => false,
    },
  };

  // Listen to the Firebase Auth state and set the local state.
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unregisterAuthObserver = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.setState({ isSignedIn: !!user });
      if (user != null) {
        this.setAuthPersistence(); // Setting state persistence here
      }
    });

  if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
    console.log("User is already signed in")
  }else{
    console.log("User is not signed in")
  }
}


  setAuthPersistence = () => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Local persistence set");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log("Local persistence has not been set");
      });
  };

  // Make sure we un-register Firebase observers when the component unmounts.
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unregisterAuthObserver();
  }

  render() {
    //Displaying firebase auth when user is not signed in
    if (!this.state.isSignedIn) {
      return (
        <div>
          <StyledFirebaseAuth
            uiConfig={this.uiConfig}
            firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <Redirect to="/signedInUser" />;
  }
}

export default SignInScreen;
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as in the answer you linked, your `if(firebase.auth().currentUser)` runs before Firebase has asynchronously refreshed the authentication state, and thus before the user is signed in again.

Any code that needs to respond to the authentication state, needs to be in the `onAuthStateChanged` callback. So:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unregisterAuthObserver = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.setState({ isSignedIn: !!user });
      if (user != null) {
        this.setAuthPersistence(); // Setting state persistence here
      }
      if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
        console.log("User is already signed in")
      }else{
        console.log("User is not signed in")
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, when your app loads after a page refresh, it renders before Firebase auth state has resolved (triggering your onAuthStateChanged callback).

A trick I like to use would be to initialize your isSignedIn state to `null`. When the onAuthStateChanged triggers, you set isSignedIn to either `true` or `false`. When rendering, you explicitly test for true or false when choosing what to return. e.g. `if (this.state.isSignedIn === false)` could return your StyledFirebaseAuth component and 'if (this.state.isSignedIn === true)` would return your Redirect.